# I forgot my laptop's bios/uefi password acer predator Helios 300 (Model::PH315-52)

Tags: bios, passwords, uefi

I forgot my laptop's bios/uefi password acer predator Helios 300 (Model::PH315-52) can I reset it by force flashing the bios if I can then please someone tell me how to and if it's not possible then suggest me a way

Comment: Force flashing the uefi bios will reset it to defaults, so yes, that will work, but it is not recommended to do that approach. You can google for reset bios acer predator helios 300 to find out how to properly reset your laptop's bios.

Comment: If its a modern laptop flashing the bios will not help, the password is stored on a separate secure chip. If the bios does not generate a code after 3-5 wrong passwords being entered, then it may have to go to an acer service center. If it does output a code try entering it here>>>https://bios-pw.org/

Comment: I did tried that website but that master password isn't working for me and yes it does generate code after 3 attempts